# Stripe Connect Direct Charge Error: Invalid token ID

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm getting the error: *Invalid token ID* when creating a `paymentIntent` through the Stripe API (NodeJS).

The following works:

```
stripe.paymentIntents
    .create({
      amount: 100,
      confirm: true,
      currency: "gbp",
      description: "payment",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      payment_method_data: {
        type: "card",
        card: {
          token: customerCard.id, // token generated on the client side
        },
      },
    })
```

But now I want to move away from a 'simple' charge to a 'direct' charge flow using Stripe Connect, as per this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges

If I amend my code as per the guide to this:

```
stripe.paymentIntents
    .create({
      amount: 1000,
      application_fee_amount: 100, // added this
      confirm: true,
      currency: "gbp",
      description: "payment",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      payment_method_data: {
        type: "card",
        card: {
          token: customerCard.id,
        },
      },
    }, { stripeAccount: "{{ ACTUAL_CONNECT_ACCOUNT_ID_IS_HERE }}"}) // added this
```

The call fails (in my try catch) with "Error: Invalid token Id: tok_abc..."

I don't understand why the `paymentIntent` is being created without error in the first case, but as soon as I try to create another `paymentIntent` using direct charge on the connect account, and taking an application fee (as per the docs), and using the exact same method to generate a new card/token (with the same stripe test card), the `paymentIntent` fails and the token which was fine before is now invalid. The error seems misleading or at least obscured.

I'm generating a new card token client side on each payment attempt exactly as per the guide, using this package: https://github.com/expo/stripe-expo. Here's how I'm generating the token:

```
import createStripe from "stripe-client"; // https://github.com/expo/stripe-expo

...

// init a new instance of stripe client passing the ID of the connected account to create the token on that account
  const stripeClient = createStripe(
    "pk_test_5...gKi",
    { stripeAccount: "{ACTUAL_ID_IS_HERE}" }
  );
  return stripeClient.createToken({ card });
```

Getting what looks to be a valid token every time.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using Stripe's ReactNative SDK (via Expo), it looks like.

Serer-side, you are creating a PaymentIntent on the Connect account with the

```
    }, { stripeAccount: "{{ ACTUAL_CONNECT_ACCOUNT_ID_IS_HERE }}"}) // added this
```

part.

Similarly, you need to create the Token on the Connect account as well.

You can do this by passing `stripeAccountId: acct_123` when you construct `StripeProvider` in your ReactNative code: https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/interfaces/StripeProviderProps.html#stripeAccountId

where acct_123 is the same account ID you're passing when you create your PaymentIntent server-side.

That would mean your Token creation would happen not on the Platform, but on the Connect account.

Comment: Thanks @hmunoz I'm actually using "stripe-client" as mentioned above on the client side. I've edited my question to show my token generation code and it does contain a "stripeAccount" header which is set to the connected account ID. It looks like I'm doing as you suggest, but either I've made an error or it's not working as expected.